# Integrate ng2Material by NPM

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem trying to integrate Angular2 with ng2Material.

I get show small buttons with the Material style but I don't know why when I click on the buttons, I can see the effect over buttons click.

Here are the steps I take with my repo:

```
npm install
bower install
npm run go
```

Here is my [Github project](https://github.com/webdeveloperfront/ng2Material_Angular2).

Comment: either post some code or working example of your code that would be better and easy to solve out your probelm.

Comment: the GitHub link, is my own example: https://github.com/webdeveloperfront/ng2Material_Angular2

I prepare this example because i want to use NPM and no PLUNKER, you know what i mean

Comment: **Important note for readers**: please satisfy yourself that the repo is safe to use before running commands on it - these commands could install malicious software in your machine. If it doubt use a temporary virtual machine, or don't download it.

Comment: no i don't get you what you want to say. here is working example for you http://plnkr.co/edit/btRKjeRNpHrASXbFPKtd?p=preview in which i am showing click event on button. hope it will help you if any doubt feel free to ask me.

Comment: Julio, would you be able to show the problem you are encountering in the question itself? Since the question is highly dependent on the repo link, this may be put on hold because it is not reasonably self-contained. I have also edited out the request for urgency - that is often not well received by **volunteers** here. Either of these may be the reason for the downvotes you've received so far.

Comment: Sorry i don't wnat that the people think that i'm a bad programmer, you can see my profile on my github account, i'm a web developer and on my job i have to integrate angular2 and ng2Material but downloading the libraries and not using "cdnjs". Please can somebody help me ?

Comment: @Julio see my working plunkr hope it will help you out.

Comment: @PardeepJain I don't use your plunker, i prepare my own Github using **NPM package**, and i can't integrate at all ng2MAterial and Angula2

Comment: @Julio who told you to use my plunkr i just ask you to see my plnkr may it will help you. i you don't want to see its okay.

Comment: @PardeepJain, can you explain me a little (or where i could found some info) why on your config.js file you use **map:{}**, why ng2-material must be there and why not on the index.html on the script area: **<script src="node_modules/ng2-material/dist/ng2-material.js"></script>**, like on my github example ? - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long as comment so posting as answer may help to someone else.

According to question @julio wants to use ng2 material buttons with effects but facing some problem while (click) event binding.

working example of same http://plnkr.co/edit/btRKjeRNpHrASXbFPKtd?p=preview

for more information read out here and you found examples too with code here

> https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material/

for using angular2 material components we have to import the .js file for same in the index.html so put this code in the index.html

```
<script src="node_modules/ng2-material/dist/ng2-material.js"></script>
```

then we have to map the material to use in the config.js file to tells the system.js (module loader) where to find these things (material). so we have to configure the config.js file as explained in the official website of angular2 material.

in order to use components of material we have to imports using module loader like this

```
import {MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-material/all';
```

then add the same in the list of directives of @component annotation.

Comment: but one question again jajajaja, sorry;  i must continue using on the config.js file on the map attribute this: **map: {app: "./src","ng2-material":"https://cdn.rawgit.com/justindujardin/ng2-material/gh-pages/v/0.2.8/ng2-material"}**, here there must be linked the ng2Material from my node, **or not** ?, if not i will continue using the link from cdn.rawgit.com, and on my job they dont want use any link from outside ... how can i resolve this ? ... Thanks

Comment: amm i have not implement this in my project yet but yes you can use local path instead of this `cdn...link` both the cases will be same.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i get it. But i have to undersatando now how the file config.js works, because i don't understando what the **map** attribute works.